# How to launch a WP8 application via a browser using URI scheme

Tags: browser, windows-phone-8

I believe that within WP8 I can register a URI for my application (i.e. myapp:) and have it launched with Launcher.LaunchUriAsync(uri)

My question is whether there is a way for me to launch the application via the browser using the same registered uri?

I have seen instances of trying to launch applications that are associated with file extensions, but can I do it with the uri scheme?

Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes - all you need to do this is to create a web page with a hyper-link of the URI format you registered and the OS will open your app if it is installed.

If your app isn't installed it will offer to open the Store for you to search for apps which support this URI scheme.

You can test this with your apps which are still in development on the emulator or device.

Comment: how to open the app from the dormant state using file uri when the application is in dormant state..I am using web browser task to open the url from my application..application is opening from the starting...Pls help me